# Android - Save and Read from file

Tags: android

I have a listview `lv_operationList`and **I'm trying to save it to a file and read it after**. I can save and read files but I dont know if what I'm saving and reading is correct.

**Basically I want to save the list rows and when I load a program I want to fill the same listview with the saved data.**

**Saving:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < lv_operationList.getAdapter().getCount() - 1; i++) {
fileOutputStream.write(lv_operationList.getAdapter().toString().getBytes());
}
fileOutputStream.close();
```

**Load?? Maybe something like this?**

```
`fileInputStream = getContext().openFileInput(programName);
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(fileInputStream));
 while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  //Read??
 }
  //and display on lv_operationList. How?
```

Comment: You need to save data, not adapter. And after retrieve data and initialize adapter again

Comment: care to be more specific?

Comment: Share code where you initialize your adapter at first. You don't need to save listview or adapter. You just need to save your data and create new listview and adapter with saved data

Comment: But I want to save and load it for example 10 days after.

Comment: Ok. You can load saved data and create a new adapter even a year after

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to append the contents to the same file so you need to use `append_mode` like this.

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("save.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
    out.write("text");
    out.write('\n');
```

in order to read them you can use this method.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
    String line;   
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                Log.i("reading line by line",""+text);
          }
```